# Gerrit reviews are visible in UI after deletion from database

Tags: gerrit

I have deleted a change id and all its references from gerrit database. But the change is still visible in UI . Although clicking on the change give 500 internal server error. How can I fix it ? I want to remove the change permanently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run a reindex of the *changes* index, either

- [offline](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/pgm-reindex.html) (with Gerrit stopped):

  ```
  java -jar gerrit.war reindex --index changes
  ```
- [online](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-index-start.html) (while Gerrit runs)

  ```
  ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit index start changes
  ```

This will update the Lucene index from which the dashboards are generated.

Comment: I did try running online reindexing but it didnt work.
Then I tried offline reindexing and it worked .I am not sure why online reindexing didnt work.Any idea ?

Comment: Was the reindexing finish when you checked?

Comment: As this seems to have worked, please mark the question as solved using the check mark. Thanks